# Почему html код в браузере и в Beautiful Soup отличается?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

В браузере в панеле разработчика показывает вот такой вот тег:

```
<input type="hidden" id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" value="03AGdBq25WAkToUZeuT7g4nM7immntzoP3yfZbJbkCOnrVgaNyLHjXhI2z-yZCOI3ZJn1_bUSyfoqfvyhURkuAD-mY1YQ7k3IHBxl1641M4vnbGstqwbpYplZ8F4MQ2xlxAOjUS0cKvmVvcPXwGdiMpIjEq3osk0ItwAKGmKgtn5fT6-Dlos7mU7X7GtNrXrk2nTUIrN9G-W944VubpLXWptMfKl2m5J5boT1eM_59HDRduOOUzPiX2zbctQSTRDs_ieyBkDJG29hFe3g2Na7EHWw8JSCxKrI1QFMmVvQh7-ppV0eiQqLNtoxy8EcW-6qHxG16cV9uqktKQdllpq_qU9EwbriAKvnuLV2ykBZEGu2d2r0kA9DB_AV__VdlUr_qsncPQ1Pi3jSE5FEDfMKWGi7US8jURtkJtwfRqGJTZ8h2gJh8bADkv5EG5XvbxKcoq3-bbTj1oM8H">
```

При парсинге с помощью beautiful-soup этот же тег выглядит так:

```
<input id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response" type="hidden"/>
```

Как мне получить значение value?

Comment: Потому что в браузере состояние страницы меняется скриптами

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Две проблемы, почему так происходит:**

1. Возможно, вы не авторизовались на сайте и тег, который вы хотите увидеть в HTML  коде страницы, могут увидеть только авторизованные пользователи.
2. Возможно, тег, который вы хотите получить, динамически подгружается javascript - скриптом. Метод `GET`, с помощью которого вы получаете HTML - код страницы, работает только один раз, он не может получать обновления, происходящие на странице. Скорее всего, вам стоит использовать `selenium` для решения поставленной задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Была такая же проблема. Решением проблемы может стать библиотека
[requests_html](https://pypi.org/project/requests-html/). Она сможет прогрузить js скрипты.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://site.com')
r.html.render()
r.html.html  # html страница, в которой отработаны js
```